# Querying AD in context of an authenticated user in an ASP.NET Core MVC webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net, directoryservices, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm working on a web application based on ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1. It provides the ability to execute several Active Directory related operations. One of them is a web based LAPS client. To communicate with AD, I'm using `System.DirectoryServices` from `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`.

Since LAPS stores its data in a computer objects AD attributes (`ms-Mcs-AdmPwd`), I need to query this attribute, e.g. like this:

```
using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, targetDomain)) {
    ComputerPrincipal computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Name, computerName);
    string password = (computer.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry).Properties["ms-Mcs-AdmPwd"].Value.ToString();
}
```

So my problem is: I need to do this in context of the authenticated user, because the attribute security permissions already control access to the LAPS passwords. I implemented cookie authentication without Identity querying `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials()` against AD in order to authenticate users. What would be the best way to achieve this without asking the user for login data a second time?

There is a `PrincipalContext` constructor `PrincipalContext(ContextType contextType, string name, string userName, string password)`, but this would require a way to store the password for each session. Storing the password in the session itself would be a bad idea, I guess.

Furthermore, I could just query the data on server side as `ApplicationPoolIdentity` or as a dedicated service account (which would then need full access to the relevant attributes of all computer objects) and then implement some logic to determine, if the logged in user is permitted to access this specific password. But this would result in unneccessary effort, since all authorization information already exist as AD DACLs.

I hope this makes sense somehow. So if anyone can push me in the right direction, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe look into impersonation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I went with a mapping approach in order to determine, if a user is allowed to access data. If the user is member of a certain AD group containing the admins of a certain department and the target computer object is located in the corresponding OU, the password will be queried and subsequently displayed. `ApplicationPoolIdentity` executes the actual AD query. Works flawlessly so far.